# SubSonic DAL, assembly not found?

Tags: c#, mysql, subsonic, subsonic2.2

I have generated a DAL layer with Subsonic2.2 for a .NET4.0 application, using c# and mysql.
Yet when I use a Collection, i have this exception on this line:

```
AnagraficaCategorieCollection a = new AnagraficaCategorieCollection().Load();
```

telling me that it cannot load or find assembly MySql.Data, version 5.2.3.0.

My project references a newer version. How can I possibly solve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use an [assembly redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx), which tells the framework to use a newer version of MySql.Data. To add the redirection, put this in your web/app.config:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.0.0.0-6.5.3.0" newVersion="6.5.4.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Note that you may need to change the version numbers to match your current assembly.

Comment: I managed to solve it the un-elegant way by downloading and referencing the older connector version, but I was searching right now some insights on assembly redirection, so thank you, very useful code snippet!

Comment: Hmmm -- it looks like publicKeyToken is the newVersion one..  I find it funny that noone by default explains which assembly information comes from.  Literally an extra sentence..  But thanks for what you did provide  -- fortunately I can try it both ways easily enough.

Comment: Ahh -- le sigh.  Didn't work, but from what I can see, it should work.  Did the whole fusion log thing and it seems to just ignore this section.  It's a very old project, which probably has other build weirdnesses -- but it's too bad for subsonic as I rip it out to keep the project working.